# Connecting to SAP HANA database via Node.js

Tags: node.js, hana, sap-business-application-studio

I'm trying to connect with the HANA database using Node.js but I'm stuck due to this error:

> Error: Connection failed (RTE:[300015] SSL certificate validation
> failed: error code: 337047686, file:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c,
> line:1914 - error:1416F086:SSL
> routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

This is the connection script:

```
const hana = require('@sap/hana-client');


const conn_params = {
    host : 'e82df3f2-da37-42a9-9378-ea7cac35e2c1.hana.trial-us10.hanacloud.ondemand.com',
    port : '443',
    uid: 'DBM_HDI_DB_1_1LU2VD9D5CJ82CA8OLZ4INFY2_RT',
    pwd: 'Lc2Fdl-XPX_Cim84O4-Pduqy.3ptUQ-8I2qXdsY_YRlBLUckgvDNEqEYyUNKAhqSrbpT0soGQNBiEZJUMKY3t2riRjuk-MhbdxiHqQG2NHnZuo7LY5TJagIBWKaYVg4S'
};

const conn = hana.createConnection();

conn.connect(conn_params)

module.exports = conn
```

PS : I'm coding on SAP Business Application Studio I also double checked my HANA instance it's running and I tried restarting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there is an issue with your SSL certificate. The corresponding connection parameters for setting up SSL can be found in the [documentation of the Node.js client of SAP HANA](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_CLIENT/f1b440ded6144a54ada97ff95dac7adf/4fe9978ebac44f35b9369ef5a4a26f4c.html?locale=en-US).

Note, that there is a property `sslValidateCertificate`, which you can set to `false` to disable validation of SSL certificates for testing purpose.